# Поиск проекта на Java

Tags: проект, java, работа

Ищу проект с использованием Java, в котором можно поучаствовать :-)
Уже перерыл sourceforge, ohloh, github, googlecode. Может у вас есть идеи и предложения ?)

UPD1. Смысл вопроса заключался в присоединение к живому проекту, а вы предлагаете пойти порешать задачки, конечно, на топкодерс есть целый чат, в котором можно пообщаться, но всё равно, это не то что я хотел найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить сходить на topcoders), заодно и денег может заработаете если повезет)

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, а можно поподробней что это за ресурс? %)

Comment: http://www.topcoder.com/
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TopCoder

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TopCoder

Comment: На вики все описно, кроме того, что там можно еще и денег заработать.

Comment: Вот пример рекламы от них на эту тему)
Compete now in the $4,000 PHP Opportunity implementing Alcatel-Lucent RESTful service.
This contest is in PHP.
This contest can win you $4,000.
This contest has 1,800 DR Points.
This contest will not affect your rating or reliability.
Use the Recess Framework to implement three RESTful services.  All functionality is already available via PHP components in the contest forum.  All you have to do is register, write your code, and submit your solution.  Good luck and may the best PHP coder win!
- Alcatel-Lucent and the TopCoder(R) Competitions Team

Comment: почитал немножко, попробую поучаствовать в algorithm competition :-)

Comment: Ага, токо советую не забывать, что топкодер,инк это коммерческая организация)))

Comment: Только деньги с некоторых соревнований могут получить только граждане США

Answer (score 2):

если читали на википедии про http://www.topcoder.com/ то наверное заметили и о codeforces.ru  - Аналогичен топкодеру но русский и не менее уважаемый

Answer (score 1):

Находите интересующий проект, смотрите в issue/bug - треккер, чините один - присылаете мейнтеймеру патч... если примут - закомитят, если нет - чините-чините...

Comment: так вопрос относится к первому предложенному вами действию - "Находите интересующий проект".

Comment: А я вопрос немного по-другому понял, что вы ищите проект в котором МОЖНО поучаствовать. Ну я и ответил что можно в любом опенсорсом принять участие. =)